# How to override something from vendor laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to override

```
 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Password\DatabaseTokenRepository.php
```

I tried this user model in app folder.. but that is not working.. Can you tell me where to put it?

Comment: There must be a better way.

Comment: please suggest me how to do that better way..

Comment: please tell us what is not working

Comment: I actually had to do something like this for my project as well. I was gonna write up an answer but saw someone had already posted one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546911/1193304

Answer (score 1):

So see this is a vendor class. If you want to override any functionality of that class you can do so by applying method overriding. Just extends the class that you wan't to override, then redefine the function that you want to override in your class. Now, you can use your own class whenever need instead of the vendor class.

For example:

```
class TokenRepo extends DatabaseTokenRepository{
    //Define the functionality here to ovrride
}
```

Usages:

```
$token = new TokenRepo();//instead of original DatabaseTokenRepository
```