# Laravel 5.4: Password reset token custom length?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 building an API where I email the user a token on password reset if user verified, which user provides before resetting password. Currently the sent token has 64 characters and too large for user to grab, and I'm not sure if laravel has configuration to give a custom length to token?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is a little bit tricky, ill try to explain the procedure as clearly as possible:

**STEP 1 - Extend the standard DatabaseTokenRepository**

Create a class that extends `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository` in order to define a new token creation policy.

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth\Passwords;

use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository;

class CustomDatabaseTokenRepository extends DatabaseTokenRepository
{

    // Overrides the standard token creation function
    public function createNewToken()
    {
        retrun substr(parent::createNewToken(), 0, 30);
    }

}
```

I've just trimmed the token generated by Laravel down to 30 chars, feel free to implement your own token generation routine.

**STEP 2 - Extend the standard PasswordBrokerManager**

Now you have to tell the `PasswordBrokerManager` to use your token repository instead of the standard one. In order to do so you have to extend the class `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth\Passwords;

use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager;

class CustomPasswordBrokerManager extends PasswordBrokerManager
{

    // Override the createTokenRepository function to return your
    // custom token repository instead of the standard one
    protected function createTokenRepository(array $config)
    {
        $key = $this->app['config']['app.key'];

        if (Str::startsWith($key, 'base64:')) {
            $key = base64_decode(substr($key, 7));
        }

        $connection = isset($config['connection']) ? $config['connection'] : null;

        return new CustomDatabaseTokenRepository(
            $this->app['db']->connection($connection),
            $this->app['hash'],
            $config['table'],
            $key,
            $config['expire']
        );
    }

}
```

**STEP 3 - Extend the standard `PasswordResetServiceProvider`**

Now you have to extend the standard `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider` in order to tell Laravel to instantiate your `CustomPasswordBrokerManager`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth\Passwords;

use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider;

class CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider extends PasswordResetServiceProvider
{

    // Override the method registerPasswordBroker
    // in order to specify your customized manager
    protected function registerPasswordBroker()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('auth.password', function ($app) {
            return new CustomPasswordBrokerManager($app);
        });

        $this->app->bind('auth.password.broker', function ($app) {
            return $app->make('auth.password')->broker();
        });
    }
}
```

**STEP 4 - Final step, replace the provider in `config/app.php`**

Comment out the following line in your `config/app.php` files under the `providers` key:

`// Illuminate\Auth\Password\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,`

And add the following line just below:

`App\Auth\Passwords\CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider::class,`

**CONSIDERATIONS**

Be careful when doing such things, the token is defined as `hash_hmac('sha256', Str::random(40), $this->hashKey)` where `$this->hasKey` is `env('APP_KEY`). This is used to ensure that no collision will occur when generating password reset tokens. I suggest you to investigate a secure method to reduce your token length securely.

Comment: Yes I guess that's the same reason laravel also hasn't provided a straightforward solution. I also figured out it wasn't secure and went on with a different solution. Thanks @Desh901 I guess i'll accept yours as the answer for the question, since you have mentioned the security concerns with the solution.

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Comment: Thank you very much!! One correction: `class CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider extends PasswordRESETServiceProvider`